# unity5, box collider 2d size doesn't match platform

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a 1x7 platform. then added a box collider 2D and set the size to 7.  you can see in the picture. the platform and box collider are not matching. how can i get it fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X Offset is the easy answer and definitely not a bad one, but maybe not the best one since it could make this problem show up in other areas.

BoxCollider2D by default has its origin at the center of the object ( where the translate tools are showing).

Since the translate tool is at the middle of the platform, the collider should be centered on it as well.

There are several possibilities that I can think of:

1. The sprites do not have their pivot at the center (If you want it
   that way, use Offset to center the box)
2. The children of the selected object are offset (They should be
   shifted over to line up with everything else, unless you need them
   this way for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty Gameobject - add any sprite objects that you need in there - press the "**GameObject**" button in the menu and select "**Centered on Children**" in order for the empty object to be centered properly. This will have to be done each time you add a new object into the bulk. Hope this helps.